# How to retrieve rows from Pandas DataFrame with same index labels in consistant way?

Tags: python, pandas

I know it is possible to use `df.xs(lbl)` to access the rows of the DataFrame with all indices equal `lbl`, however, I have the following issue:

I want to be able to iterate through a time series `T` (simple sequential `list` of `datetime`s) as follows:

Where `dfA` is a dataframe indexed by all `T`, and `dfB` is a dataframe with multiple (some repeated) indices from `T`, but not all `T`

```
for t in T:
    for r in dfB.xs(t).iterrows():
        # do something with r on values in dfA @ t
    # do something else with values in dfA @ t
```

The problem I am having is:

1. If `t` is not in `df`, a `KeyError` is raised.
2. If there is only one entry for `t` in `df`, a `Series` object results
3. If there are more than one `t` in `df`, a `DataFrame` object results

As you can see, this would make for rather ugly code for something that should be fairly straight-forward.  I am sure there must be a more *pandasic* way of doing this, but it is not obvious to me.

**Update:**

Dumps of `T` and `dfB` as follows:

Note: I have changed `T` in the original code to a `DatetimeIndex`, but this should not change the original premise.

```
In [26]: T
Out[26]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2000-03-15 00:00:00, ..., 2012-12-26 00:00:00]
Length: 3191, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [27]: orders #equivalent to dfB
Out[27]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 15322 entries, 2000-03-15 00:00:00 to 2012-12-27 00:00:00
Data columns:
Symbol    15322  non-null values
Type      15322  non-null values
Number    15322  non-null values
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
```

This is enough data to get the original code snippet working, if `pandas` behaved as I expected/hoped it should.

Additionally, to show that `dfB` contains multiple indices of the same values at places:

```
In [30]: orders.xs(t) #equivalent to dfB.xs(t)
Out[30]: 
             Symbol Type  Number
Date                            
2012-12-26  0596.HK  Buy    1000
2012-12-26  0387.HK  Buy    1000
2012-12-26  0342.HK  Buy    1000
2012-12-26  0343.HK  Buy    1000
2012-12-26  0491.HK  Buy    1000
```

Comment: Hi Dallas, please could you include the output of df.to_dict() and dfB.to_dict() that way we can use these rather than make up our own, that would be very helpful for us.

Comment: Also please could you be a bit more specific about the `#do something...` bits?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `dfB.reindex(T).iterrows()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

I get `TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not iterable`.

If I attempt to wrap it in a list(), I get `Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`.